# Write a function to output min, average, and max given input of values for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, function, output

I have 3 variables (A, B, and C) each containing 10 values (1 values per row) and I would like to create a range (output) or three columns for each variable. Basically given the 10 values for A, B, and C, I want to automate an output that gives me the min, avg, and max value for each variable in R. I was thinking of using a function and my input being the three variables.

I used excel but once I get more data, I will have trouble outputting the values. I used a condition statement and manually fed in the values - I would like to create three new columns corresponding to each range (Min, Avg, and Max) per variable.

```
#Create a DataFrame
## Random Matrix - Three Variables - 50 rows ##
trial <- matrix(sample(100, replace = TRUE), ncol=3)
colnames(trial) <- c('MFP', 'ECU', 'HMU')
trial.table <- as.table(trial)
trial <- as.data.frame(trial)

## Creating Min, Average, and Max range for each Column ##


# setting blank vector to fill #
# Create new double vector: output
df2 <- data.frame(matrix("", ncol = 3, nrow = 1)) 
colnames(df2) <- c('Min_thresh', 'Average', 'Max')


# Alter the loop
for (i in trial$MFP) {
  # Change code to store result in output
  df2$Min_thresh <- min(trial$MFP)
  df2$Max <- max(trial$MFP)
  df2$Average <- mean(trial$MFP)
}

# Print output
df2
```

Expected output would be three columns added to a blank df that shows min, average, and max values pulled from each column:

```
df3 <- data.frame(matrix("", ncol = 3, nrow = 1)) 

df3$min <- min#
df3$average <- avg#
df3$max <- max #
```

I would then populate each column given the range of Min, min to avg, and then Max value... where Avg is the delta between Avg and the min (like a range with 10 being the Min and 16 being the Avg.).

Comment: what does this have to do with R?

Comment: show your expected output ?

Comment: maybe first create function and when you get error then ask question.

Comment: I included R just in case it was easier to do it in there. I will update the output.

Comment: I edited the comment/question to be more clear and just in R (no longer in Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Base R,

```
t(sapply(trial, function(x) list(min = min(x), avg = mean(x), max = max(x))))
```

(Note that the result is a `matrix` with your original column names as the rownames.)

If you like pipes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
trial %>% 
  melt %>%
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarize(min = min(value), avg = mean(value), max = max(value))
```

(Result is a 4-column data frame, giving the original variable in the first column.)